# What would be a valid OleDbConnection ConnectionString for an uploaded file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, connection-string, oledbdataadapter

I am certain I have missed something obvious.

A simple task is before me:  'Upload an Excel (2003) file via ASP.NET on a Forms page and push the contents of that file to a DataTable in preparation for data- validation / storage'.

Those operations work fine already when applied to a locally stored edition of the file -- for that I simply utilize the **OleDbConnection-ConnectionString** "String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName)" from an **OleDbDataAdapter**.

However, trying to repeat that with an uploaded edition of the very same file (via a FileUpload control), on the line where I fill the **OleDbDataAdapter** I receive the error [*"The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object "Sheet1$".  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."*]  An error so generic and painful -- still I'm unsure where to look next.  I am guessing the connection-string structure is illegitimate for an uploaded file.

I searched through StackOverflow and MSDN and even around the web with no success thus far, but the search terms may be overly ubiquitous.  Am I required to actually find a local repository for saving the uploaded file to prior to attempting a parse of it's content?  Can I not simply construct a connection to a 'file in memory'?  In case it concerns the answer, the uploaded files are not anticipated to ever exceed 200 kb in size.

**Sincere thanks in advance for any assistance provided...**

Comment: Yes, you need to temporarily save it to disk..

Answer (score 3):

What I do in this situation is build a `Parser` class that will temporarily save the file, process it, then delete that temporary file when disposed.  Something like:

```
 public class ExcelParser : IDisposable
 {
    string filename;
    string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"";

    public ExcelParser(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
       filename = String.Format("{0}{1}.xlsx", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
       file.SaveAs(filename);
    }

    public MyData Process()
    {
       OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format(connStr, filename));
       conn.Open();

       OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn);
       OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while (reader.Read())
       {
          // Build Data to return
       }

       reader.Close();
       conn.Close();
       return data; // Return data you built
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       File.Delete(filename);
    }
 }
```

You could then use it as such:

```
using (ExcelParser parser = new ExcelParser(file))
{
   var results = parser.Process();
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: When I find time to try this out, if it works as hoped I'll give you that 'answer' credit you will surely have earned :).

Comment: Do you have any problem with deleting the file after it's been In use from IIS?